# Question about convergent sequences in a metric space

Tags: real-analysis

I am confused about the following question:

Suppose I have some metric space $(X, d)$, and I have a convergent sequence $(p_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ that converges to some $p \in X$.

I have been asked to prove that $(\{p_{n}\})^{\prime} \subset \{p\}$.

I do not quite understand how this is possible since isn't $\{p\}$ just one element? Furthermore, isn't $p$ a limit point, so how could it be a proper subset? Does anyone have an idea of what this could mean?

Comment: "$\subset$" does not mean proper subset.  "$\subsetneq$" means proper subset.

Comment: Can you show $p$ is **a** limit point of $\{p_n\}$?  What happens if $\{p_n\}$ has two limit points?

Comment: @EricTowers so is the idea that, given I have a limit point, I need to show that there exists a sequence which converges to that limit point?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that for a set $A\subset X$ the set $A'$ is defined to be a set of cluster points of $A,$ i.e a set of points $x\in X$ such that $x\in \overline{A\setminus \{x\}}.$
In this notation it is easy to see that if you take $A=\{ p_n :n\in \mathbb{N}\} $ where $(p_n )$ converges to some $p\in X$ then $A' =\{p\}.$

Notice that usually the set of cluster points of the set $A$ is denoted by $A^d$ and sometimes is called a derivative of the set $A.$